# xrander problem with 1900x1080p

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, xrandr

i have a problem with xrandr
i successfully executed the following :

```
#cvt 1900 1080
#xrandr 1900x1080 170.75  1904 2024 2224 2544  1080 1083 1093 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

but unfortunately the following command :

```
#xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1900x1080
```

returned the following error :

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Major opcode of failed request:  153 (RANDR)
Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
Serial number of failed request:  29
Current serial number in output stream:  30
```

the following command output might help in identifying problem :

```
#glxinfo |grep -i opengl
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce 310M/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL version string: 3.3.0 NVIDIA 310.14
OpenGL shading language version string: 3.30 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
OpenGL extensions:

#lspci |grep -i vga
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [GeForce 310M] (rev a2)
```

any ideas what's gonna be wrong ?

Comment: Did you try 1920 instead of 1900 (most screens have 1920); otherwise, why 1900 ?

Answer (score 0):

You want full-size of your screen with nvidia ? it works here:

> sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.old
>
> sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
>
> sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh xserver-xorg
>
> sudo reboot

Comment: i have tried your instructions but it seems
    sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh xserver-xorg
didn't generate new xorg.conf file, and screen resolution still didn't exceed 1152x864  "1360x768 available but not appropriate"