# nvidia-settings writes xorg.conf but doesn't load settings

Tags: 12.10, nvidia, settings

I made my changes on `nvidia-settings` and also writed the changes to xorg.conf (yes, I checked the file).

After rebooting the settings are only applied after I open nvidia-settings agains, any way I can fix this? Right now I'm running this bs at startup: `timeout 1 nvidia-settings`

Happens with all available drivers (nouveau, current/experimental). The original `--load-config-only` that was on startup doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried to open the nvidia-settings as a root ? `gksudo nvidia-settings` .

Comment: Yes, you can only write those changes with privileges. All the files are getting written since I can see the file AND like I said I can also load it when I open nvidia-settings, but it's supposed to work with --load-config-only too

Comment: Maybe the behavior changed or maybe it is a bug. So with root privileges works as it should (?).

Comment: I can't understand your comment, but if it's about running the same commands as root/sudo/gksudo I tried it all. Not even `sudo nvidia-settings --load-config-only` works, I also tried recompiled drivers.

Answer (score 1):

#### LOAD ONLY SOLUTION

After using the nvidia-settings GUI just as user, edit the `~/.nvidia-settings-rc` user file, and remove your host name prefix from all lines, leaving just ":" to start those lines. Just use replace all (your hostname) to nothing, in most editors.

Then, optionally set the file to read only; to lock any further changes. Otherwise `nvidia-settings GUI` changes will add your host name back to the file.

Or you can rename the edited file, and tell nvidia-settings to use it when loading:
  nvidia-settings -l --config=/home/user/my_edited_nvidia_settings_rc

You just have to remember to set the file to read and write, to unlock your settings, so the GUI will change them again, if needed. Alas, then, you have to remove the hostnames from it again.

I use this to set a correct gamma/color (green cast) for photography editing, with Nvidia cards. My monitor settings don't do it right.

Why removing hostname works, I don't know; but it does! Now I don't have to close the auto loaded nvidia-setting dialog every time I boot up (without the "-l"), and the darn "-l" (that's an L for load only) option works; when `nvidia-setting -l` is loaded as a startup application.

Comment: that exact tip solved for me :)

Comment: just created a bug about this here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-settings/+bug/1333510

Answer (score 0):

nvidia-settings seems still to be unsolved. it is not working here either.

if you need full screen for nvidia - then here is my answer:

[xrander problem with 1900x1080p](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228808/xrander-problem-with-1900x1080p)

I tried with this to solve nvidia-settings-frickle too, - but it did not help here.
You can test if this helps at your machine ?!

Comment: I don't have any problems with the resolution settings (I think the xorg.conf is actually getting loaded, just not the .nvidia-settings-rc). It's just gamma, brightness, etc.. and probably AA settings but I don't have any game here to confirm it

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same problem and came with a half (or quarter of a...) solution.

Simply issue in the terminal these commands:

```
$ nvidia-settings & sleep 2 && killall -v nvidia-settings
```

or for more convenience, you could place this on the desktop in a executable bash script:

```
#! /bin/bash

nvidia-settings & sleep 2 && killall -v nvidia-settings
```

I didn't got luck issuing this script on Startup preferences nor in .profile file on user home folder. If I use this script on .profile, desktop environment loading waits for the whole script execution (when using something like

```
#! /bin/bash

sleep 15
nvidia-settings & sleep 2 && killall -v nvidia-settings
```

...) and when it finishes, seems like that the right settings in .nvidia-settings-rc are overriden by something else

But in the meantime I have a quick way to apply my color correction.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem. Don't know the answer for sure. I think it has something to do with loading the .nvidia-settings-rc file when you log in. That is just my guess.

This link might help also: http://eric.biven.us/2008/02/16/ubuntu-and-nvidia-settings-how-to-make-those-settings-reapply-themselves-next-time/

Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Alas this does not help. nvidia-settings silently exits.